# Setting Openstack compute node with a fake hypervisor

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm trying to set up openstack compute nodes that *mimics* a real node, however never actually sets up the VMs on a physical host.
In the openstack tests, there are usages of fake drivers (defined in `nova/virt/fake.py`) through a complex system of testing classes.

I wish to get such a node up and running ***not***  within a test (meaning, I don't want to use these classes to spawn the compute node), but on an actual VM/container, however, I cannot figure out how to get a compute process to run with this fake hypervisor (or more specifically, one that will be defined by me).

How do I inject this fake driver instead of the real driver in a compute node?

*(also, I'm installing OS using devstack (latest))*

For more clarification, my goal is to do stress testing of OS, running multiple fake compute nodes, **not** in all-in-one configuration. The usage of devstack to setup the controller node is for simplifying the process, but the system should be:

- A controller node, running the core services (Nova, Glance, Keystone etc.).
- Multiple compute nodes, using fake hypervisors on different machines.

Comment: The Devstack docs have a [section](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/nova.html#fake-virt-driver) about this driver.

Comment: @berndbausch I have seen that, but I need to inject my own implementation of the fake driver. I'm not doing an API testing (as described there, and the reason the fake driver doesn't check the quotas).

Comment: You could deploy Devstack with the fake driver as described, then replace `fake.py`with your code.

Comment: @berndbausch and if I want to deploy the compute node on a different server? (not all-in-one formation)

Comment: A compute node can only have one hypervisor driver, but you can have heterogeneous hypervisors in the cloud. Therefore, install your `fake.py` on all those compute nodes where you want it.

Comment: @berndbausch it gave me the idea where to look for this option, added it below in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing a new compute node, there is a configuration file `nova-compute.conf` that is being created automatically.

It seems that in `/etc/nova/nova-compute.conf` there is an option:

```
compute_driver = libvirt.LibvirtDriver
```

That uses `libvirt` as the default hypervisor for a compute node. In addition to `hyperv`, `vmwareapi` and `xenapi`, according to the [nova configuration documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/compute/config-options.html), one can choose using the fake driver by changing this option to:

```
compute_driver = fake.FakeDriver
```

In order to set the fake driver to our implementation, we may replace the fake driver written in `fake.py` with something else.